# To work under the advisory of?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, nouns, american-english

I want to describe my current research-assistant position saying that "I work under the advisory of John Green". Is this the correct way of saying that my advisor is John Green? If not, what is the better way to state the whole sentence?

Comment: This is not even close to correct (look up *advisory* in the dictionary). You could say "My advisor is John Green" or "I am being advised by John Green."

Comment: I'm not so sure, Peter - there are 300 000+ Google hits for "under the advisory of" - and the first few show a wealth of different instances from academic-sounding sources. The object of the pronoun 'of' can be a person in authority, or an academic (or perhaps other) body.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thanks for helping me out,  I'm not a native speaker.  Do you think I could use it then?

Comment: Here in the US, I would say "I work under the direction of John Green."

Comment: @EdwinAshsworth: [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+the+advisory+of%2C+under+the+advisorship+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seems to suggest you should use "under the *advisorship* of" rather than *"advisory of"*. This sounds much better to me.

Comment: I would say, I work under the guidance of.

Comment: @Peter Shor Perhaps the OP's version conveys the sense of a more formal arrangement than _advisorship_ (= Talia's 'guidance') does. I haven't been privy to Unispeak for many years now - OP should ask John Green or some other advisor on the use of the phrase.

Comment: this is a common mistake from speakers of latin languages.

Comment: @gcb I assume you mean Latin languages. I think I'll give my vote to the staff at the  [University of North Michigan Medical Center: Office of Postdoctoral Education](https://www.unmc.edu/postdoced/about/advisory/index.html) who accept the usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Advisory* does appear as a noun in OED, but it is not used to mean "advice" or "supervision", which is the meaning required here. In addition to unrelated uses, an *advisory* is a body headed by an Adviser (rather like a Directorate is headed by a Director), or which is formed to advise a company on relevant matters.

OED has it as a North American word.

> 1915 The meetings of these different advisories were held in the city of Washington.
>   1990 The official bodies included the Advisories of Defense, Intelligence, Science, Religion, and so forth, as well as the Native Matters Advisory.

Google's results for "under the advisory of" could include this use: *He worked under the Advisory of Defense,* for example.

In the OP's example, naming an adviser, one might say

> In my work I am advised by John Green.
>   John Green acts as adviser for my work.

Comment: While *advisory* itself is a noun used in the U.S., I haven't heard it used in the OP's sense in U.S. universities.

Comment: One doesn't need 'advisory' to mean 'advice / supervision' here, if one uses / is prepared to accept the relevant prepositional object for the relevant sense of 'under'. Collins lists a single relevant sense: ' **under** (prep) 4. subject to the supervision, jurisdiction, control, or influence of' while AHD subcategorises here: **under** prep. ... 7. Subject to the authority, rule, or control of: under a dictatorship. 8. Subject to the supervision, instruction, or influence of: under parental guidance. Neither dictionary forbids 'under the advisory (/ dictatorship! / administration) of ....

Answer (score 3):

I believe *advisement* is the word you're looking for. Try this:

"I work under the **advisement** of John Green."

You also could say: "I work under the **supervision** of John Green."

I'd also consider using the present progressive tense instead since you're work is ongoing.

"I am working under the advisement/supervision of John Green."

That's how we'd phrase it in the US.